# Getting nodeName/elem is null on DataTables 1.10.4

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatables

So I have a html page with html table and this script

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('table').DataTable();
    })
</script>
```

It is working fine when I tried to change the total entries shown or search, but the console give me an error 'Cannot read property 'nodeName' of null' on Chrome or 'elem is null' on firefox. I'm using jquery 1.11.1 and this is the culprit (jquery-1.11.1.js:3618) :

```
jQuery.acceptData = function( elem ) {
    var noData = jQuery.noData[ (elem.nodeName + " ").toLowerCase() ],
        nodeType = +elem.nodeType || 1;

    // Do not set data on non-element DOM nodes because it will not be cleared (#8335).
    return nodeType !== 1 && nodeType !== 9 ?
        false :

        // Nodes accept data unless otherwise specified; rejection can be conditional
        !noData || noData !== true && elem.getAttribute("classid") === noData;
};
```

The error is thrown because elem is null, I'm a beginner in js so anyone know if this is jquery fault or datatables bug?

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: just check the order in which you have included jquery files in your page..first include jquery file and then add datatable.js file.

Comment: i believe it is already in correct order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, it was caused by $('#backend').validate().settings.ignore = []; in my Layout page.